# TYPO3 - Can you extend the News-Extension with a Plug-In field?

Tags: php, xml, typo3, extbase

I use the [content_rating_extbase Extension](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/content_rating_extbase/) but it cannot rate the news pages because they do not have the field to add a plug-in.

Is it possible to extend the TCA or Flexform of news with a general plugin?
If it is, how?

Comment: Hi, check out [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to ensure you will receive more attention.

Comment: I have no code to show, is there something you did not understand in my question ?

Comment: just for clarification: what plugin should be added to what data?

Comment: Add link to the plugin mentioned in question

Comment: https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/content_rating_extbase/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you have no "news" pages in TYPO3.
You have news-records and you have pages (based on pages-records) where news-records are shown (with the help of plugin contents).

In TYPO3 each records is 'stored' in a page, even pages itself. so you get a tree of pages and in the pages you have content (tt_content) or data (e.g. news records in a page with type sys-folder).

For displaying news you use plugins which can be configured to show a list of news records or just one single record. The configuration can be typoscript or fields in the plugin or even URL parameter.

with the extension realurl (or similar) you can build URLs which give the impression of individual pages for each page. the base of this is a page with a plugin which evaluates the URL-parameter to decide which single news should be shown in detail.
If you want more content after each news-record on each of these 'pages' you just can add more content to the page. e.g. a plugin for rating which enables rating of news. just make sure the rating plugin works with the current URL (or identifies the resolved/translated URL parameters.

Comment: as added to your question: be more specific with your expectations and question.